# Qpython android sensors returning None

Tags: android, python, qpython

I am testing the androis API using qpython but when I try using the sensors, it returns me [None, None, None]

The code should work as it is the same as some exemple on internet. Anyone had this problem and solved?

```
### android API test ###
import androidhelper, time
droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.startSensingTimed(1, 255)
time.sleep(1)
s = droid.sensorsReadOrientation().result
droid.stopSensing()
print s
```

Answer (score 2):

While the code is running, make the sensors of device to sense something (I mean speak, shake device, type, etc.) thereby giving chance for it to sense.

Then, it should not display `[None, None, None]` instead of which it displays some values saying its ability to sense.

**Note**: While running code don't keep device ideal.